# How to make an Excel chart with vba that have two category axis

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in excel sheet like this

```
Country Product Price
America A   43
China   B   13
Germany C   21
Turkey  D   12
```

In excel i select this data and make a chart out of it that seems like this

[image: Graph from excel]

But the problem is when i select the same data with vba and draw the chart from vba then it results into

[image: Graph from vba]

Now i want the vba chart to display to category axis as same as we select data from excel and draw the chart.

In short i want the vba chart to automatically adjust according to the data.

Here is the code.

```
Sub CreateChart()

         Range("a1").Select
         Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
         myrange = Selection.Address
         mysheetname = ActiveSheet.Name

         Worksheets(1).Activate
         'ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

         ' Add a chart to the active sheet.
         ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(125.25, 60, 301.5, 155.25).Select
         Application.CutCopyMode = False

         ActiveChart.ChartWizard _
            Source:=Sheets(mysheetname).Range(myrange), _
            Gallery:=xlColumnStacked, Format:=10, PlotBy:=xlRows, _
            CategoryLabels:=1, SeriesLabels:=1, HasLegend:=1, _
            Title:=charttitle, CategoryTitle:=chartcategory, _
            ValueTitle:=chartvalue, ExtraTitle:=""

      End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add your code plz? Edit your post to include it ;)

Comment: @R3uK please have a look at code.

Comment: In `ActiveChart.ChartWizard`, simply change `PlotBy:=xlRows` to `PlotBy:=xlColumns`.

Comment: The code `ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(myrange)` works.I want to ask one more thing.How i can group my data in chart.For example if i have two products in country america then i want it to group by in such a way that america should appear once with two products.Hope you understand  @Jon Peltier.[link](http://peltiertech.com/chart-with-a-dual-category-axis/)

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want without seeing the data and chart. Usually you have to accomplish the grouping in the data, not in the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple in Excel. Record a macro while inserting the chart and selecting the data for the chart. The recorder records the VBA steps and gives you the neat code which can do the same whenever you execute. For instance, the recorder gave me this 2 lines of code:

```
Sub Macro1()

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A2:C5"), PlotBy:=xlColumns

End Sub
```

Pretty simple, isn't it?

Comment: The code `ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(myrange)` works.I want to ask one more thing.How i can group my data in chart.For example if i have two products in country america then i want it to group by in such a way that america should appear once with two products.Hope you understand  @Vimalraj Selvam.[link](http://peltiertech.com/chart-with-a-dual-category-axis/)

Comment: It's a good idea to explicitly add `PlotBy` to `SetSourceData`, and not rely on the default being what you want (I've edited the answer to reflect this).

Answer (score 0):

If you just wana to update data in already existing chart, better solution can be to update them. Basicaly create chart which you desire and assign some name to it. (for example myLovelyChart)

```
Sub updateChartSO()

        Dim chartSheet As Worksheet
        Set chartSheet = Sheets("testSheet")

        Dim chtSerie As Series

        With chartSheet
            For Each chtSerie In .ChartObjects("myLovelyChart").SeriesCollection

                'specify your values, can be specified by array or even from sheet'
                chtSerie.Values = ""
                chtSerie.XValues = ""
            Next

        End With


End Sub
```

Or if you really wana to create new chart, take a closer look at `chartType` property (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820803.aspx) and its enumeration (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838409.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, it auto define the format based on data range.

However, You can using below code to control it

```
Chart(1).PlotBy = xlRows
```

OR

```
Chart(1).PlotBy = xlColumns
```